# Namespace for IOC Container

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control

In Global.asax file, I have the following code.

```
config.DependencyResolver = new IoCContainer(unity);
```

In IOCContainer, it is showing as "Namespace not found". What Namespace we should include here. I already included Microsoft.Practices.Unity.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, go to the keyword `IoCContainer` and press `ctrl + .`

Comment: Well, where is the class you're looking for defined?  That would be the namespace you need.  I don't see a definition for `IoCContainer` in `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.aspx

Comment: Where does `IoCContainer` come from? It is not a Unity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the following classes. This took me a while to find aswell.
Found the below code reference [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver)

```
class ScopeContainer : IDependencyScope
{
    protected IUnityContainer container;

    public ScopeContainer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
        {
            return container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (container.IsRegistered(serviceType))
        {
            return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}

class IoCContainer : ScopeContainer, IDependencyResolver
{
    public IoCContainer(IUnityContainer container)
        : base(container)
    {
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
        return new ScopeContainer(child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of EntLib are you using? Until 4.1, it had UnityContainer and not IoCContainer.

Edit: What is that unity object you are passing? You may have to post some code. Meanwhile, [here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42524/A-basic-introduction-to-the-Unity-Application-Bloc) a tutorial that can help you out.

Comment: UnityContainer does not take arguments. But here 1 argument need to take.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Namespace not found'?

Look at your "using" directives at the very top of the file and check if any of them is undelined with red color. Maybe you have some typo? Or maybe you have forgotten to "add reference" to some library?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Nuget package [`Unity.Mvc3`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc3) and then use the following code:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```